# Object has no attribute 'btn'

Tags: python, kivy

I am following a tutorial and trying to implement a button in a .kv file. 
I expect to be able to run the main.py file and enter name and email information. When I press the submit button, I expect it to output the name and email to console and clear the text input boxes. Upon pressing the submit button I get an AttributeError:

> 'GusApp' object has no attribute `'btn'

I've checked my indentation and verified the method `'btn'` is in my main python file.

**main python**

```
class Grid(Widget):
    name = ObjectProperty(None)
    email = ObjectProperty(None)

    def btn(self):

        print("Name: ", self.name.text, "email: ", self.email.text)
        self.name.text = ""
        self.email.text = ""

class GusApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Grid()
```

**gus.kv**

```
name: name # global variable id name
email: email # global variable id email

GridLayout:
    cols: 1
    size: root.width - 200, root.height - 200
    pos: 100, 100

    GridLayout:
        cols: 2

        Label:
            text: "Name: "

        TextInput:
            id: name
            multiline:False

        Label:
            text: "Email: "

        TextInput:
            id: email
            multiline:False

    Button:
        text:"Submit"
        on_press: app.btn()
```

Comment: Try changing `on_press: app.btn()` to `on_press: root.btn()`

Answer (score 0):

The error message suggests that Python is looking for the attribute `btn` in the class named `GusApp`, but your code appears to define this attribute in the class `Grid`.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to get the button to work by changing 'on-press: app.btn()' to 'on-press: root.btn()'.

The kivy documentation and Steve helped me understand KV rule context. I recommend looking at this link if you're experiencing similar issues: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html?highlight=binding